# Can manual tests be incorporated in a pipeline as a required step?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, manual-testing

I would like to have manual test as a required step in a release pipeline, much like automated tests in build.

Tried to find if this was possible in Azure Devops

I would expect manual testing as a required part of a release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can manual tests be incorporated in a pipeline as a required step?

For this issue , I am afraid it is currently not supported in azure devops. Compared with manual testing, integrating automatic testing in the pipeline is more in line with the CI/CD concept.
Adding a manual test is more of a requirement. In addition, the default timeout for the pipeline is 60min. If the wait time for the manual test times out, it may cause a failure.

So we can't directly incorporate manual tests in pipelines. The workaround provided by Nima is an indirect way.

If you really need this feature,you could submit a feature request in our [Develop Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, now iI know!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new stage with approval right after the draft deploy (dev environment). In the first step, deploy your app in a server. The the specific user can do a manual test, then approve the deployed artifact as a release condidate. Finally, your production step will run after the user confirmation.

[image: Release pipeline with approval step]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!
But does this mean that the manual test run is not _really_ required. This is more of a reminder or question if it has been run?
I would like it to be an "automatic" requirement that the manual test has been run and is Passed.

Comment: I got it. You have to define an approval gate alongside an approval user in the indirect scenario that i've mentioned. Look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops) article. Also the article about [gates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=azure-devops) is pretty useful.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the links. Anyway, I think the answer from Hugh Lin disencourages me to go further with this for now. But interesting all the same!

Answer (score 0):

if we are using TFS 2010 for release management we can create the test case in Microsoft test manager 2010 and at the time of production release we can make a mandatory check to validate the test cases. we will write the test case using Microsoft test manager and will link this test case with TFS Win no. once we move the source code from UAT to production we will make a mandatory check to validate the test case created in Microsoft test manager